# How to to nest a sequence with Q?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I would like to handle a sequence of tasks and get informed as soon as a block of those tasks is completed and once every task is completed. The output I expect should be `1,2,3 - 4,5,6 - 7 - 8`. With my current implementation I get `1,4,7,8 - 2,5 - 3,6`

```js
function handleTasks(tasks) {
    var deferred = Q();
    var promises = []

    tasks.forEach(function (task) {
        promises.push(function () {
            return handle(task);
        });
    });

    promises.reduce(Q.when, new Q()).then(function () {
        // Finished inner hunk.
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

function handle(t) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    document.write("started " + t);

    Q.delay(5000).then(function () {
        document.write("finished " + t);
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}

var deferred = Q();
var tasks = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8]];
var promises = []

tasks.forEach(function (task) {
    promises.push(function () {
        return handleTasks(task);
    });
});

promises.reduce(Q.when, new Q()).then(function () {
    // Finished all tasks
    deferred.resolve();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.6/q.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm really not sure how your code is producing any output at all. You're trying to use a promises as though they were deferreds, and you're using `document.write()`, which I would imagine is overwriting your whole page.

And while not necessarily a bug, you are using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

So I'm not really sure why you got the result you did, but here is a cleaner approach that produces the desired result:

```js
function handleTasks(tasks) {
    var promiseFuncs = tasks.map(function (task) {
        return function () {
            return handle(task);
        };
    });

    return promiseFuncs.reduce(Q.when, new Q()).then(function () {
        console.log("finished " + JSON.stringify(tasks));
    });
}

function handle(t) {
   console.log("started " + t);

    return Q.delay(5000).then(function () {
        console.log("finished " + t);
        return t;
    });
}

var tasks = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8]];
var promiseFuncs = tasks.map(function (task) {
    return function () {
        return handleTasks(task);
    };
});

promiseFuncs.reduce(Q.when, new Q());
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.6/q.js"></script>
```

You can also eliminate some of the duplication here with a helper function:

```js
function runSequence(items, action) {
    return items.map(function (item) {
        return function () {
            return action(item);
        };
    }).reduce(Q.when, new Q());
}

function handleTasks(tasks) {
    return runSequence(tasks, handle).then(function () {
        console.log("finished " + JSON.stringify(tasks));
    });
}

function handle(t) {
   console.log("started " + t);

    return Q.delay(5000).then(function () {
        console.log("finished " + t);
        return t;
    });
}

var tasks = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7], [8]];
runSequence(tasks, handleTasks);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/q.js/0.9.6/q.js"></script>
```

Comment: This helps a ton! Thank you for pointing out that I used the deferred anti-pattern, I didn't know about that one and will rewrite it to get a better understanding of what is going on.